# Remote Desktop: Prompt before logging off user

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I have a Windows XP Pro machine that I regularly log into remotely to work on.  If there is already a user logged into the machine it will inform the user that someone is trying to log in and that they will be logged off and gives them 30 seconds to cancel the operation before timing out and letting me log in.

Now, when I try into my Windows 7 Ultimate machine, if there is user already logged in it just allows me to log in without prompting.

Is there any way to make the RDP server prompt the logged in user before letting me log in remotely?

Comment: In Win7 is the local user's session forcefully logged out to allow you to log in, or does that session remain active, in addition to your RDP session?

Comment: It is logged out, or locked if the same user is trying to log in.

Comment: Are you connecting as the same user as the logged in one?

Comment: Yes, the same user is logging in remotely and logged in locally.

Comment: Your current setup on windows xp is exactly what i need to setup.  Any ideas how I do this please?  There is just 1 user logged physically logged in and we all just use RDP with that same user to login remotely.  thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also remote into my Windows 7 Ultimate machine, which has three user accounts. Here's what occurs for me:

- If no account is logged in, no one receives a prompt and I'm able to remotely connect immediately
- If my remote account is logged in, no one receives a prompt and I'm able to remotely connect immediately
- If one of the two other accounts is logged in, they receive the 30 second prompt that I'm attempting to log in remotely

Is this what you are experiencing?

Comment: Ahh.. I think the different users may be the key.

Answer (score 0):

This article might help you to enable Concurrent Sessions on the Win7 computer.

Enabling Concurrent Sessions allows you to Remote Desktop into a system that someone else is on, **under a different user account**, and access the system without kicking the user off.

[Guide: How to Enable Concurrent Sessions in Windows 7 RTM](http://www.missingremote.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=3692&Itemid=232)

(Note: I haven't had the opportunity to test this at first-hand.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm not necessarily looking for concurrent sessions, just the behavior I saw previously in Windows XP

Comment: No information I could find discusses this problem. All I can suggest is updating to RDP 7 if you haven't done so : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969084, where the behavior might (or might not) change.